# What makes this community unique?

Tags: discussion, scope, new-users

I originally had a question about what makes something 'vegan' but as I explore Stack Exchange, I realize I may have misunderstood the purpose of the whole community. I am new to doing anything on Stack Exchange outside of looking for solutions to computer issues.

I thought that because 'vegetarian' and 'vegan' share the site identity, that the community questions would be primarily about food choices, strategies and preparation. It never claimed that, I just assumed it. But I didn't know about the [tour](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/tour) page.

It says the site is "for those committed to a vegan or vegetarian lifestyle" but that didn't really say why it's here. There are vegan, vegetarian, nutrient, and other similar questions on the cooking.se site.

In my experience, 'vegan' is an everyday term interchangeable with 'plant-based.' It is common in our culture to use them interchangeably when talking about diet. Actually, 'plant-based' is a lot less common, and the [distinctions](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/276/is-there-a-difference-between-vegan-and-plant-based) have nothing to do with their diet.  I know people who take their ethics in diet and apply them throughout their lives.  But I've not known any of those people to call themselves 'vegetarians.' They would more likely identify as 'vegan.'

This is my confusion with the site.  The link between vegetarians and vegans in the identity implies a common ground of removing meat from the diet.  That style of eating is already represented in the cooking.se site, is it not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vegetarianism and veganism isn't only about cooking.

- perhaps you want to know where to get shoes that aren't made of leather?
- or whether you can buy a car that doesn't contain animal products - leather seats may be obvious but is there anything else?
- and if you aren't going to travel by car and you don't have any shoes, [how are you going to get where you're going](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/314/are-there-any-considerations-a-vegan-might-make-when-choosing-transportation/329#329)?
- maybe you want to know if there are animal products in [your electronics](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/1007/are-most-electronics-vegan-vegetarian)?
- or perhaps you want to know whether your cosmetics have been tested on animals, or even whether they are still being tested on animals?

None of the above questions involve food but they are all things that both vegans and vegetarians would seem to want answers to.

Comment: I understand your point, and if the site was presented as a 'values-based' take on vegetarianism and veganism, it would totally make sense. But other than the words 'committed' and 'lifestyle', the description is pretty generic and open to interpretation. The term 'vegan' is all over the Internet and in documentaries commonly understood to be talking about the diet. Specifically, a plant-based diet. But the terms are used interchangeably. 'Vegetarian' is also ethical, but food is the usual context.

Comment: Ask a new meta question and propose new wording if you want to.